# Getting! Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client | Express

Tags: mongodb, express, express-router

I'm getting Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client and then some long list with location of errors when doing an POST request is express route. I saw similar answers, got many but I couldn't catch where I'm missing.

Here I'm attaching the code sample of that particular POST request.

```
    .post(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next) => {
    Favorites.findOne({user: req.user._id})
    .then((favs)=> {
        if(!favs) {
            Favorites.create({user: req.user._id, dishes: req.body})
            .then((favs)=> {
                console.log('Favs created: ', favs);
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.json(favs);
            }, (err) => next(err))
            .catch((err) => next(err));
        }
        else {
            var noofids = req.body.length;
            for (var i=0; i<noofids ; i++) {
                if(favs.dishes.indexOf(req.body[i]._id) > -1) {
                    res.json('It is already in the dishes');
                }
                else {
                    favs.dishes.push(req.body[i]._id);
                    favs.save()
                    .then((doc) => {
                        Favorites.findById(doc._id)
                        .populate('User').populate('Dishes')
                        .then((fav) => {
                            res.statusCode = 200;
                            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                            res.json(fav);
                        }, (err) => next(err))
                        .catch((err) => next(err));
                    }, (err) => next(err))
                    .catch((err) => next(err));
                }
            }
        }
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));

})
```

When doing the **if** part it executes without error but when doing **else** it shows long list of errors.

```
POST /favorites/ 200 7.864 ms - 29
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at done (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1004:10)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:374:12)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:417:11)
    at View.render (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\app.js:84:7
    at Layer.handle_error (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (E:\CourseraMERN\NodeJS\conFusionServer\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

How to rectify this issue? Thanks!

Comment: My expectations from the code is that if favorite document doesn't exist for a user i.e user is adding his first dish to favorites then create the `Favorites` document. And if user is adding dish for a second time or onwards then it follows the code of `else` block. A user can add an array of dish_id and it is the duty of the code to check if particular id is already present in the favorites then ignore it with the message 'it's already in dishes' else add the new dish to favs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to `return` every `res.json()` statement otherwise the code will continue to execute lines underneath it and you have code that sets the headers in multiple locations, which is causing the error:

```
.post(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next) => {
    Favorites.findOne({user: req.user._id})
    .then((favs)=> {
        if(!favs) {
            Favorites.create({user: req.user._id, dishes: req.body})
            .then((favs)=> {
                console.log('Favs created: ', favs);
                res.statusCode = 200;
                res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                return res.json(favs);
            }, (err) => next(err))
            .catch((err) => next(err));
        }
        else {
            var noofids = req.body.length;
            for (var i=0; i<noofids ; i++) {
                if(favs.dishes.indexOf(req.body[i]._id) > -1) {
                    return res.json('It is already in the dishes');
                }
                else {
                    favs.dishes.push(req.body[i]._id);
                    favs.save()
                    .then((doc) => {
                        Favorites.findById(doc._id)
                        .populate('User').populate('Dishes')
                        .then((fav) => {
                            res.statusCode = 200;
                            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                            return res.json(fav);
                        }, (err) => next(err))
                        .catch((err) => next(err));
                    }, (err) => next(err))
                    .catch((err) => next(err));
                }
            }
        }
    }, (err) => next(err))
    .catch((err) => next(err));

})
```

Comment: Still the issue didn't resolved sir. When the program returns `return res.json('It is already in the dishes')` it terminates and waits for another request. I've explained my program working by adding a comment to my question. In brief I want that i adde an array of ids in the body and code starts checking it if the particular id is already present in favorites or not. If present then do this `return res.json('It is already in the dishes')` and if not then add to favorites. And if I remove return from `return res.json('It is already in the dishes')` then it starts giving same HTTP_HEADERS error

Comment: I think it might be inside a for loop, so you are setting the headers multiple times

Comment: So, what changes I should make into this?

Comment: Take your `return` statements out of the loop and `fav.dishes.push` before you return any response to the client so that only one response is sent

Comment: Sorry for replying this late. Yes! It did solved my issue. I kept pushing into the array in the for loop and saved it and sent headers once after the loop.